# How to launch server in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'm trying to launch the server in rails.

I used: rails server from the command prompt in the directory of my rails project and I got this: http://content.screencast.com/users/rockstarvisible/folders/Jing/media/a5fef1ba-d062-45ff-b80c-61516977be07/2012-02-06_1438.png

the prompt said there was a missing dll file, so i got that particular file from an old version of mysql's bin and copied and pasted that dll file into rail's bin. It's still not launching (command prompt is giving me the same text as in the screen shot above every time i do: rails server in the command prompt).

Comment: I advise you reinstall mysql.

Comment: Use this third party gem. Fixed it for me https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped using windows and started using Mac and that fixed it.